# Adding NM cable into side hole on service panel, code securing?

Tags: wiring, basement, code-compliance

Service panel in basement is mounted directly to block wall just below the joist. I want to add new circuit cables, NM-B-14-2, through side holes using a knockout clamp. If the side hole is more than 12” below the joists do I need to secure the cable between the hole and the joist? How should it be secured?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is probably to attach a 1x6 flat to the block wall on either side of the panel as a cleat for staples.  That will let you keep it tidy without too much work or expense.